# Usage of :link in vue-apollo example unclear

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo

I am currently working through the vue-apollo example on [howtographql](https://www.howtographql.com/vue-apollo/2-queries-loading-links/) and I can't get any further at the following point:

```
    <link-item
      v-for="link in allLinks"
      :key="link.id"
      :link="link">
    </link-item>
```

I tried to replace "link in allLinks" with "item in allLinks" and I get an error, because it seems that changing :link the application will not work anymore. I haven't found any useful resources of this :link binding. Even removing it breaks the app and I am not sure what's the problem with that.

Comment: Can you give us the error and do your objects look exactly the same

Comment: Did you replace `link` with `item` in all 3 places in your example?